# If I put only the bootjar code in the build.gradle file, an error occurs. What could be the problem?

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, gradle

If there is no bootjar in the build.gradle file,
the project runs fine, but an error occurs if only the bootjar code is put in.

Doing bootjar run from eclipse tools is also working fine.
What's the problem?

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}


group = 'com.infoget'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:3.0.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.23'
    implementation group: 'org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2', name: 'log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1', version: '1.16'
    
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    
}
```

I want put in this code in the build.gradle file

```
bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.infoget.prototype.Application'
}
```

code and configuration modify

Comment: Please share the error that you get when you include the `bootJar` configuration and the command you are using to run the build.